# RIPEMD 160 Hashes

Tags: public-key, ripemd160

I have observed that BTC Address 1111111111111111111114oLvT2 has the public key RIPEMD 160 Hash is **0000000000000000000000000000000000000000** whereby 111111111111111111112BEH2ro has the public RIPEMD 160 Hash is **000000000000000000000000000000000000000A** many of address has been generated in this sequence of 160 hash among them many dormant wallets which were active in past few years and still has positive balance.
what my question is how these address has been created ? does they really have private key ? if yes then is the private key would be sequential as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are probably "proof of burn" addresses.

The corresponding private key is unknown. If the private key was known, the public key hash would look much more random. By creating a non-random-looking public key hash, one proves that they *almost certainly don't* know the corresponding private key. If nobody knows the private key, bitcoins sent there are effectively deleted.

Why would someone delete bitcoins? Well, for example, it's one way to start up a new alt-coin. You can give people altcoins in exchange for deleting their bitcoins. Some people consider this more fair than giving out altcoins based on proof-of-work or random chance.

Comment: You are right regarding the proof of burn but unfortunately not 100 percent i have a database for sequence of 1111111111111111111114oLvT2  to  1zzzbRUbAnKUAJ6fEhX1g1ZzMz6ur3BJW these are total 25202952 keys all of their hash 160 are in sequence , among them 30% keys are still active 30% were active in past few years but now dormant and 40 % keys just received the coin but never spend its mean 60% had the valid private keys. if it is same like i am thinking their private key might be in specific key range with specific sequence

Comment: @MuhammadAdnanAlam Sequential private keys do not produce sequential public key hashes. There's no known way to guess a private key based on a public key hash.